# Capturing all text between delimiters only when there is a line feed

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to capture the text between 2 delimiters only when there is also a line feed within the delimiters.  So for example if we have the following text.

```
Organisation Name <<me.company.name>>
ABN/ACN <<me.company.abn>>
Contact Name <<me.name>>
<<me.PhoneNumber

Another line>>
Email <<me.emailAddress>>
```

I am wanting to only return the <<me.PhoneNumber \n\n 'Another Line>>

the \n could be anywhere - basically only matches that have at least one \n within the << >> and ignore all other << >>

The pattern I have so far is <<(.*?\n*)*?>> but this captures all << >> (I'm using C#)

here is an example of what I have tried
https://regex101.com/r/sb0wCs/1

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<<((?:(?!<<|>>).)*?\n(?s:.)*?)>>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3m6WH1/1). *Details*:

- `<<` - a `<<` string
- `((?:(?!<<|>>).)*?\n(?s:.)*?)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:(?!<<|>>).)*?` - any zero or more chars (other than newline chars) that do not start `>>` or `<<` char sequence, as few as possible
  - `\n`  - a LF char
  - `(?s:.)*?` - any zero or more chars (including newline chars), as few as possible
- `>>` - a `>>` string

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern `<<(.*?\n*)*?>>` you have a capture group and all parts are optional including the newline, so the non greedy quantifier `*?` can match until the first occurrence of `>>`

Also when repeating a capture group, the group value will hold the value of the last iteration, so instead you can put the capture group without a quantifier around the whole part that you want to capture.

---

If your strings start at the beginning of the line, you can use anchors and match at least a single line in between that does not start with either << or >>

```
^\s*<<(.*(?:\r?\n(?!<<|>>).*)+\r?\n)\s*>>$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*<<` Match optional leading whitspace chars and <<
- `(` Capture *group 1*

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!<<|>>).*)+` Match a newline, and repeat at least 1 line not starting with `<<` or `>>`
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s*>>` Match optional leading whitspace chars and >>
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zRy8sj/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `<<[^>]*?\n[^>]*>>`

Test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/vD3EgE/2

```
<<[^>]*?\n[^>]*>>

<<      match literal <<
[^>]*?  match any char that is not > as few as possible
\n      match a newline
[^>]*   match any char that is not > as few as possible
>>      match literal >>
```

- This will match a only if there is `\n` between `<<` and `>>`.